# Place an animated div under another div with z-index

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I am developing a web app with jQuery mobile, I need to put on div (`#number1`) under the other (`<div class=ui-block-a>`), but the `z-index` property doesn't work !!

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3cZ9k/1/)**

**HTML:**

```
<div id="welcome-page" data-role="page">    
    <div id="content" data-role="content">
        <div id="userdata"> 
            <div id="weightdata" class=ui-grid-b>
                <div id="number1" >1
                </div>
                <div class=ui-block-a>
                    Enter your <span>thing</span>:
                </div>
                <div class=ui-block-b></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#userdata {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-shadow: none;
    border-radius:5px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:absolute;
    right:7px;  
    top:3%;
    left:7px;
}
#weightdata {
    color: #000000 !important;
    background-color: #06b4c8; /*blue*/
    padding-left: 10px;
}
#weightdata .ui-block-a {
    -webkit-transition: all 1.0s  ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1.0s  ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1.0s  ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 1.0s  ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1.0s ease-in-out;    
    text-shadow:0px 0px 0px #444;
    color:black;
    z-index:20 !important;
}
#weightdata .ui-block-a.active {
    text-shadow:0px 0px 40px #444;   
    color:white;
    z-index:20 !important;
}
#weightdata #number1 {
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1.0s  ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1.0s  ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1.0s  ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: opacity 1.0s  ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 1.0s ease-in-out;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 7%;
    color: white;
    z-index: 10 !important;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: bold;
    display:block;
    opacity: 0;
}
#weightdata #number1.active {
    opacity: 1;
    display:block;
    z-index: 10 !important;
}
#weightdata .ui-block-a { width: 35% !important; margin-top: 13px;}
```

Can you help please ?

Comment: sorry it is in the fiddle because it's too long !

Comment: @Louis it is not too long, I just added it and it looks fine.

Comment: can you provide an image of what you are looking for ?

Comment: @jsve, ok thanks, I thought it was too bulky. aloisdg I'd like, from back to front: the bluebackground, then the number 1, then the text "Enter your thing"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only use `z-index` on positioned elements,

```
#weightdata .ui-block-a
    position: relative;
    z-index:20;
}
```

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3cZ9k/2/)

Answer (score 0):

To your #weightdata .ui-block-a ,you need to add z-index less than 10 and position other to static so:
z-index:1; position:relative;
would do the job